# Center layout that is wider than browser CSS

Tags: css

I have exported a layout from Photoshop and has a width of 2400px. My screen has 1200px resolution width and the layout appears aligned to left.

I need to have some elements positioned absolutely inside a div that will center itself. First of all, is that possible;

I have included my divs in a wrapper that has a margin: 0 auto; but it doesn't seem to work. What is the obvious that I am not able to see ?

http://jsfiddle.net/pxWSt/

Comment: works for me in chrome, ff and IE9.

Comment: If you run the jsfiddle code you will see that it aligns left the whole div and the text does not appear at all because it is centred. I need to center the div, regardless the width.

Comment: Centering with `margin:0 auto;` only works if wrapper has a fixed width.

Comment: already tried that. not working http://jsfiddle.net/pxWSt/3/

Comment: yup in your case this won't center since the div is wider than browser window. Does the wrapper div keep same width all the time?

Comment: Would you mind dropping some browser support (Old ones, and Opera)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/pxWSt/5/

Essential part:

```
.container
{
    margin-left:50%;
    left:2500px;/*half of its own width*/
}
```

The commented out `calc()` part can be used to replace it. Too bad Opera doesn't support `calc()`.

Comment: It does the work it supposed to do but it uses fixed placement. I mean, it's too easy to think "I'll set a negative margin half the width" and I do not think it's a nice way to do this.

Comment: @RobertoDelgazzo Not every problem has a "general solution". In particular, "percentaged" `width`, `height`, `top` and `left` always refer to parent node, not to mention `position:absolute`d element will always ignore alignment setting of parent node. If you insist on making this "general", I'll suggest combining JavaScript.

Comment: @RobertoDelgazzo This way you will not be able to scroll properly.

Comment: Also you are cutting away the part that is left to the screen.

Comment: @Christoph I guess that's what the OP mean: use the DIV kind of like `background: url() top center`; that's why I explicitly set `overflow-x:hidden` in my fiddle. Otherwise is very difficult (if possible) to archive this without JS.